# How to save all data inputed in fragments into database on click of completed using material stepper library

Tags: java, android

I am using this library - https://github.com/stepstone-tech/android-material-stepper to build a step by step registration system where users will fill each field one by one before finally saving users data into the database using a php script via JSON.

I have 2 problems.

**1.** After filling the data, I dont kow how to save the data that has been inputed into the database.

**2** How to validate each data been inputed individually onClick of 'NEXT' button. (Although, number 1 is much more important for now, but if someome could help me out with both, GREAT!.)

I have done this with the use of just one activity and it works fine.

**One of the fragment. 6 of them (They are all similar)**

```
public class EmailRegisterFragment extends Fragment implements Step {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_email_register, container, false);

    //initialize your UI

    return v;
}

@Override
public VerificationError verifyStep() {
    //return null if the user can go to the next step, create a new VerificationError instance otherwise
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onSelected() {
    //update UI when selected
}

@Override
public void onError(@NonNull VerificationError error) {
    //handle error inside of the fragment, e.g. show error on EditText
}
}
```

**One of the fragementLayout (They are all similar)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".UsernameRegisterFragment"
android:orientation="vertical">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/back_left_light"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:onClick="goToWelcomePage"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Your Email Address"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:padding="20dp"
    />


<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/EditTextTheme"
    >
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:hint="Input Your Email"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:id="@+id/email"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/edit_text"
        android:theme="@style/EditTextTheme"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
        />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:onClick="goToRegisterWithPhone"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:text="You dont have an email? Click here"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

**Activity layout (That shows the NEXT, BACK COMPLETE Button and progress bar)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.stepstone.stepper.StepperLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/stepperLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:ms_stepperType="progress_bar"
app:ms_nextButtonColor="@color/white"
app:ms_completeButtonColor="@color/white"
app:ms_backButtonColor="@color/white"
/>
```

**ActivityJava file**

```
public class IntroActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements StepperLayout.StepperListener{

private StepperLayout mStepperLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    //remove action and status bar

    if (getSupportActionBar() != null)
        getSupportActionBar().hide();

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_intro);


    mStepperLayout = (StepperLayout) findViewById(R.id.stepperLayout);
    mStepperLayout.setAdapter(new MyStepperAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), this));
    mStepperLayout.setListener(this);


}

@Override
public void onCompleted(View completeButton) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onCompleted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onError(VerificationError verificationError) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onError! -> " + verificationError.getErrorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onStepSelected(int newStepPosition) {

}

@Override
public void onReturn() {
    finish();
}

public void goToWelcomePage(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, WelcomeActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
public void goToRegisterWithPhone(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, IntroActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

Like I said I have done this with the use of just one Activity using the Volley library. Check it out.

**RegisterActivity.java**

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText username, email, password;
private Button btn_register_final;
private ProgressBar loading;
private TextView login_text;

private static String URL_REGISTER = "http://78d24f21.ngrok.io/misnap/register.php";
SessionManager sessionManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    sessionManager = new SessionManager(this);

    username = findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
    email = findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
    password = findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    btn_register_final = findViewById(R.id.btnRegisterFinal);
    loading = findViewById(R.id.loading);
    login_text = findViewById(R.id.btnLoginText);


    btn_register_final.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //do something here after clicking register
            Register();
        }
    });


    login_text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


}

public void Register(){
    loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    btn_register_final.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    final String username = this.username.getText().toString().trim();
    final String email = this.email.getText().toString().trim();
    final String password = this.password.getText().toString().trim();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_REGISTER,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        String success = jsonObject.getString("success");
                        if(success.equals("1")){
                            sessionManager.createSession(username, email);

                            Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("username", username);
                            intent.putExtra("email", email);
                            startActivity(intent);

                            loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            btn_register_final.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Unable to register" + e.toString(), 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        btn_register_final.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Unable to register" + error.toString(), 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    btn_register_final.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            })
    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("username", username);
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("password", password);
            return params;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
}
```

**Register.php**

```
<?php
require_once("connect.php");
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
$username = $_POST['username'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password)
 VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$password')";

 if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
    $result["success"] = "1";
    $result["message"] = "success";

    echo json_encode($result);
    mysqli_close($conn);
 }

 else{
    $result["success"] = "0";
    $result["message"] = "An error occured";

    echo json_encode($result);
    mysqli_close($conn);

 }
}
?>
```

How do use this same logic for the fragments??

Answer (score 0):

this might be late but i think it would help to others. So for sure you can validate/Insert or whatever you want to do with your inputs on Next button click before going to next step, This is how you can do it in Kotlin

```
 // To be somewhere inside your Step

override fun verifyStep(): VerificationError? {
        if (validateStep()){
            return null
        }
        else
            VerificationError("Any error message")
    }
```

Now here validateStep will be a function that returns `True` or `false` depending upon your needs. Here is a simple example of a `validateStep()` function. Here you can do anything like insertion or validation etc.

```
private fun validateStep(): Boolean {

        var isValid = true

        val name = binding.etCustomerName.text.toString()
        val email = binding.etCustomerEmail.text.toString()
      

        if (name.isEmpty()) {
            isValid = false
        } 

        if (email.isEmpty()) {
            isValid = false
          
        } else if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
            isValid = false
        }


        return isValid
    }
```

Do let me know if it helps anyone. Happy coding :)